# How to iterate over regex expression

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have the following String:

```
name1=gil;name2=orit;
```

I want to find all matches of `name=value` and make sure that the whole string matches the pattern.

So I did the following:

1. Ensure that the whole pattern matches what I want.

   ```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^((\\w+)=(\\w+);)*$");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
   if (!m.matches()) {
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. Iterate over the pattern `name=value`

   ```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(\\w+);");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
   while (m.find()) {
       map.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
   }
   ```

Is there some way to do this with one regex?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can validate and iterate over matches with one regex by:

- Ensuring there are no unmatched characters between matches (e.g. `name1=x;;name2=y;`) by putting a `\G` at the start of our regex, which mean ["the end of the previous match"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
- Checking whether we've reached the end of the string on our last match by comparing the length of our string to [`Matcher.end()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end()), which returns the offset after the last character matched.

Something like:

```
String line = "name1=gil;name2=orit;";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\G(\\w+)=(\\w+);");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
int lastMatchPos = 0;
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
   System.out.println(m.group(2));
   lastMatchPos = m.end();
}
if (lastMatchPos != line.length())
   System.out.println("Invalid string!");
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/M9FMUO).

Comment: How can I adjust this Pattern if I want to permit delimiters (e.g., ','), but not permit it at the beginning or end of the input?

Comment: Your `line` is exactly the format I'm trying to parse so I'd upvote twice if I could!

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable multiline-mode for "^" and "$" to work as expected.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:(\\w+)=(\\w+);)*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
while (m.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount() - 2; i += 2) {
        map.put(m.group(i + 1), m.group(i + 2));
    }
}
```

Comments where right, you still have to iterate through matching groups for each line and make the outer group a non-capturing group `(?:...)`.

Comment: by default regex engine matches in multiline mode.did you wanted to use dotall option!.also given the example in question,your regex wont work..

Comment: @Anirudh: No, by default, MULTILINE mode is not enabled in Java. DOTALL option will be useless here.

Answer (score 1):

```
String example = "name1=gil;name2=orit;";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((name[0-9]+?=(.+?);))+?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
// verifies full match
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Whole String matched: " + matcher.group());
    // resets matcher
    matcher.reset();
    // iterates over found
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("\tFound: " + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("\t--> name is: " + matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Whole String matched: name1=gil;name2=orit;
    Found: name1=gil;
    --> name is: gil
    Found: name2=orit;
    --> name is: orit
```

Comment: This really is 1 regex, but it requires 2 passes over the input string (once in `matches()` and once in the loop with `find()`)

Comment: @nhahtdh You're right. But I wasn't aware of any "1 pass" limitation here.

Comment: Not really a limitation, just to say that it is not that much different from OP's current solution in term of the number of passes.

Comment: @nhahtdh You have a point. What lead me to this is that the OP's solution didn't display nested passes I guess.