# regex break string into words in dictionary

Tags: java, regex

I want to create an regex in order to break a string into words in a dictionary. If the string matches, I can iterate each group and make some change. some of the words are prefix of others. However, a regex like `/(HH|HH12)+/` will not match string `HH12HH` [link](https://regex101.com/r/6X6GDY/2). what's wrong with the regex? should it match the first `HH12` and then `HH` in the string?

Comment: What about `/(HH(?:12)?)+/`

Comment: @EliSadoff I have to keep `HH` and `HH12` because when iterating the group I need to know it is `HH` or`HH12`. also, this is just an example. imaging that you only have an dictionary and `HH` and `HH12` are in the dictionary. words in the dictionary are changing as well.

Comment: Switch the alternations, it is matching `HH` first and then there is nothing more to match. Or add `$` to the end of the pattern.

Comment: @SebastianProske thanks. but even through I add the `$`, there is still one group rather than 2. [link](https://regex101.com/r/6X6GDY/3)

Comment: Let me precise: you want to make sure the string consists of `HH12` or `HH` only, and if yes, tokenize into `HH` or `HH12`? Or do you only want to get consecutive `HH`/`HH12`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match an entire string in Java that should only contain `HH12` or `HH` substrings. It is much easier to do in 2 steps: 1) check if the string meets the requirements (here, with `matches("(?:HH12|HH)+")`), 2) extract all tokens (here, with `HH12|HH` or `HH(?:12)?`, since the first alternative in an unanchored alternation group "wins" and the rest are not considered).

```
String str = "HH12HH";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("HH12|HH");
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
if (str.matches("(?:HH12|HH)+")) { // If the whole string consists of the defined values
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        res.add(m.group());
    }
}
System.out.println(res); // => [HH12, HH]
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/PUm6hZ)

An alternative is a regex that will check if a string meets the requirements with a lookahead at the beginning, and then will match consecutive tokens  with a `\G` operator:

```
String str = "HH12HH";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:HH12|HH)+$))(?:HH12|HH)");
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(res);
```

See [another Java demo](http://ideone.com/Xgyncq)

*Details*:

- `(\\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:HH12|HH)+$))` - the end of the previous successful match (`\\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) start of string (`^`) that is followed with 1+ sequences of `HH12` or `HH` (`(?:HH12|HH)+`) up to the end of string (`$`)
- `(?:HH12|HH)` - either `HH12` or `HH`.

Comment: great! what do you think of this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16817458/1646996? it also use `\\G` but doesn't looks like this complicated.

Comment: It depends on what you need, you have not precised. I explained in my answer: if you need to make sure the string *only* consists of the tokens meeting your pattern, you must first qualify the string for tokenization. That is why I suggested a more complex pattern with a lookahead and splitting the `\G` into `^(?=...)` and `\G(?!^)`. `\G(?:HH12|HH)` will match multiple tokens from the start of the string only, and if there is another text after them in the string, the matches will be still collected.

Answer (score 1):

In the string `HH12HH`, the regex `(HH|HH12)+` will work this way:

```
HH12HH
^ - both option work, continue
HH12HH
 ^ - First condition is entierly satisfied, mark it as match
HH12HH
  ^ - No Match
HH12HH
   ^ - No Match
```

As you setted the `A` flag, which add the anchor to the start of the string, the rest will not raise a match. If you remove it, the pattern will match both `HH` at the start & at the end.

In this case, you have three options:

- Put the longuest pattern first `/(HH12|HH)/Ag`. [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqyOcZ/1)<sup>The one I prefer.</sup>
- Mutualize the sharing part and use an optional group `/(HH(?:12)?)/Ag`. [See second demo](https://regex101.com/r/BG7Goj/1)
- Put a `$` at the end like so `/(HH|HH12)$/Ag`

Comment: then how to match the entire string?

Comment: thanks! but there is only one group match. what if I want all the groups. e.g, first group should match `HH12` second group `HH`

Comment: @qqibrow which language is it? Also, see [Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)

Comment: java. is there a way?

Comment: @qqibrow one easy solution is to use a global capturing group: `((?:HH12|HH)+)`

Comment: but still, there is only one matching group.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is entirely related to the way the regex engine decides what to match.

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296918/6083675), there are some regex flavors that pick the longest alternation... but you're not using one. Java's regex engine is the other type: the first matching alternation is used.

Your regex works a lot like this code:

```
if(bool1){
    // This is where `HH` matches
} else if (bool1 && bool2){
    // This is where `HH12` would match, but this code will never execute
}
```

The best way to fix this is to order your words in reverse, so that `HH12` occurs *before* `HH`.

Then, you can just match with an alteration:

```
HH12|HH
```

It should be pretty obvious what matches, since you can get the results of each match.

(You could also put each word in its own capture group, but that's a bit harder to work with.)