# Extract all substrings beginning and ending with a regex from large string

Tags: java, regex

I have a large string which contains multiline-substrings between two constant marker-strings, which I can identify with a regex.

For simplification I named them `abcdef` and `fedcba` here:

```
abcdef Sed lobortis nisl sed malesuada bibendum. fedcba
...

abcdef Fusce odio turpis, accumsan non posuere placerat. 
1
2
3
fedcba

abcdef Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin ultrices fedcba
```

How can I get all the occurrences *including* the markers from the large string?

Comment: `abcdef[\s\S]*?fedcba`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("abcdef[\\s\\S]*?fedcba");
Matcher m = r.matcher(sInput);
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group() );
}
```

where `sInput` is your string to search.

`[\s\S]*?` will match any number of any character up to the following `fedcba`. Thanks to the `?` it's a non-greedy match, which means it won't continue until the last `fedcba` (as it would if it was greedy), thus giving you the separate strings.

Comment: This is a good start, but seems to find only the first match (line).

Comment: I really don't *speak* java (just a googler ;), but I think you could simply replace the `if (m.find( )) {` with `while (m.find()) {`. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16817458/2064981

Comment: There is one more specification which I forgot to mention. abcdef always must be the beginning of a line. How can I add that to the pattern?

Comment: I found it, like this: (?m)^ Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143304/how-to-use-java-regex-to-match-a-line

Answer (score 0):

**REGEXP:**

```
(?:\babcdef)(?:.*\n)*(?:\bfedcba)
```

**JAVA:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(?:\\babcdef)(?:.*\\n)*(?:\\bfedcba)";
final String string = "patata\n"
     + "abcdef\n"
     + "Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin ultrices\n"
     + "Testing\n\n"
     + "test[](test)\n"
     + "Testing\n"
     + "fedcba\n"
     + "Testing\n\n\n\n";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL TEXT:**

```
patata
abcdef
Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin ultrices
Testing

test[](test)
Testing
fedcba
Testing
```

**RESULT:**

```
abcdef
Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin ultrices
Testing

test[](test)
Testing
fedcba
```

**See:** https://regex101.com/r/xXaLgN/5

Enjoy.

*Do not forget that if I help you, mark me as the answer to the question.*