# Iterate over regex in vavr

Tags: java, regex, vavr

What is the idiomatic way to iterate over the matches returned by a regexp in java.

Usually the java way is the following (see [How to iterate over regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817031/how-to-iterate-over-regex-expression))

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(\\w+);");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    map.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

Besides the possible mistake of calling `.group` before `.find` this is **imperative** and as such **non composable**. This means that you need to create intermediate structures to store data via side effects.

How to use regex using the power of vavr iterators/collections?

Comment: The fact that you answer your own question doesn't mean your question can be vague :) Can you please try and make your question a bit more clear?

Comment: I'll try to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple oneliner

```
  //given
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(\\w+);");
  String line = "name1=gil;name2=orit;";

  Iterator<Matcher> all = 
    Iterator
      .continually(pattern.matcher(line))
      .takeWhile(matcher -> matcher.find());

  //use it like
  io.vavr.collection.Map<String,String> map = 
    all.toMap(m->m.group(1),m->m.group(2));
```